# OleDbProvirer, db2, при чтении записей E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: c#, db2

IBM DB2

На некоторых серверах при попытке чтения записей вылетает такой Exception

'IBMDADB2' failed with no error message available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005).
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult hr)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.BuildSchemaTableRowset(Object handle)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GenerateSchemaTable(OleDbDataReader dataReader, Object handle, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchemaInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, SchemaType schemaType, IDbCommand command, String srcTable, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet dataSet, SchemaType schemaType, IDbCommand command, String srcTable, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet dataSet, SchemaType schemaType)
at BusinessLogiс.DB2.Database.GetData(String query, String database, String host, String port, String login, String password)

```
public static DataTable GetData(string query, string database, string host, string port, string login, string password)
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = Connection.GetConnection(database, host, port, login, password);
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

            return dataSet.Tables[0];
        }
        finally 
        {
            Connection.CloseConnection(connection);
        }
    }

ublic static OleDbConnection GetConnection(string database, string host, string port, string login, string password)
    {
        string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=IBMDADB2;Database={0};Hostname={1};Protocol=TCPIP;Port={2};Uid ={3};Pwd={4};", database, host, port, login, password);
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        return connection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло удаление строки

```
dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
```